# how to filter multiple values from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of json elements. and I want to filter the array based on the specific values. below is the array.

```
var arr = [
{name: bobby, id: 1, age: 23},
{name: charls, id: 2, age: 28},
{name: indi, id: 3, age: 23},
{name: charlie, id: 4, age: 25}]
```

from the above array I want to filter only staff whose names are bobby && indi. I have tried below  code.

```
var filteredArray;
for (var i =0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].name === 'bobby' || arr[i].name === 'indi'){
        filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

but through the above code, I need to mention OR(||) conditions too many times and these number of names can change like 1 time I want only staff with Bobby name and other time I want Bobby, Indi and Charlie. is there a way to make it dynamic. if yes, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript filter check for multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807783/javascript-filter-check-for-multiple-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store names that needs to be filters in an array and then check if name exists in array or not

eg.

```js
var arr = [
    {name: "bobby", id: 1, age: 23},
    {name: "charls", id: 2, age: 28},
    {name: "indi", id: 3, age: 23},
    {name: "charlie", id: 4, age: 25}
]
const names = ["bobby", "indi"];

const filtered = arr.filter((item)=>{
  return names.includes(item.name)
});

console.log(filtered)
```

For older(eg. IE11) browsers -

```js
var arr = [
    {name: "bobby", id: 1, age: 23},
    {name: "charls", id: 2, age: 28},
    {name: "indi", id: 3, age: 23},
    {name: "charlie", id: 4, age: 25}
]
const names = ["bobby", "indi"];

const filtered = [];

for(var i =0; i<arr.length - 1; i++){
  if(names.indexOf(arr[i].name) > -1){
      filtered.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Hi @hussain.codes, for the quick response. but its giving me syntax errors in IE 11. does IE 11 support filter and includes functions. can you please help me with this.

Comment: IE 11 does not support arrow function, i have updated the answer .

Comment: Hi @hussain.codes, I have tried the above code, but it says object doesn't support property or method 'includes' error. if there is any work around or this, can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter items as followings:

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'bobby', id: 1, age: 23},
  {name: 'charls', id: 2, age: 28},
  {name: 'indi', id: 3, age: 23},
  {name: 'charlie', id: 4, age: 25}
]


const keywords = ['bobby', 'indi'] // You can add keywords to be filtered to this array to make it dynamic
const filtered = arr.filter(item => keywords.includes(item.name))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of names you want to filter and then:

#### if you want to stick to pre-ES6 coding:

```js
var arr = [{
    name: 'bobby',
    id: 1,
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'charls',
    id: 2,
    age: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'indi',
    id: 3,
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'charlie',
    id: 4,
    age: 25
  }
];

var names = ['bobby', 'indi'];

var filteredArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (names.indexOf(arr[i].name) > -1) filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(filteredArray);
```

#### or, if you are willing to switch to ES6+ coding:

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'bobby',
    id: 1,
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'charls',
    id: 2,
    age: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'indi',
    id: 3,
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'charlie',
    id: 4,
    age: 25
  }
];

const names = ['bobby', 'indi'];

const filteredArray = arr.filter(item => names.includes(item.name));

console.log(filteredArray);
```